# How to upload image/media file from React to Django API?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-react

I am able to save the data without the image field. I am new to react so don't know pretty much about this type of problems. What is the problem with the image field?? this isn't showing me any error just my image data is not saving. I am sharing all my code it will be really helpful if you guys help me out.

#models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    full_name = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    image =  models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

#views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def add(request):
    data = request.data
    test = Test.objects.create(
            full_name = data['full_name'],
            address = data['address'],
        )
    serializer = TestSerializer(test, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

#this is screen for react page

```
import React from 'react';
class Test extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            full_name:'',
            image: '',
            address:''
            
        }
        this.changeHandler=this.changeHandler.bind(this);
        this.submitForm=this.submitForm.bind(this);
    }

    // Input Change Handler
    changeHandler(event){
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]:event.target.value
        });
    }

    // Submit Form
    submitForm(){
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/orders/test',{
            method:'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify(this.state),
            headers:{
                'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            },
        })
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then((data)=>console.log(data));

        this.setState({
            full_name:'',
            image: '',
            address:''
            
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <table className="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <td>
                            <input value={this.state.full_name} name="full_name" onChange={this.changeHandler} type="text" className="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Voucher</th>
                        <td>
                            <input value={this.state.image} name="image" onChange={this.changeHandler} type="file" className="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    
                    <tr>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <td>
                            <input value={this.state.address} name="address" onChange={this.changeHandler} type="text" className="form-control" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="2">
                            <input type="submit" onClick={this.submitForm} className="btn btn-dark" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
}

export default Test;
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly remove null=True, blank=True from Test model in image filed.

Comment: why? if I did this will it work? I don't think so brother

Comment: It's not giving error because you have allowed null and even in add method defined in view you're not defining image field. 
To check properly, please remove null=True and try again (Postman can be a good tool for this) 
for better understanding and reference, please visit this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/imagefield-django-models/.